# react prevent default is not working (sometimes)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first project with react and so far I haven't had any problems with the prevent default function. However, there is a page where I have 3 submit buttons and sometimes the first button will prevent default without any problems, but then I click the second and it never works. Sometimes the first button won't work either and refresh ignoring the prevent default. I tried to cancelable method and it returns true (on the first button when it doesn't reload the page). I'm pretty stumped here, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

the functions that the three buttons use

```
const submitHandlerT = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTemperatureV({temperature: detailsT.temperatureV, time: detailsT.timeV1});

}

const submitHandlerP = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPressureV({pressure: detailsP.pressureV, time: detailsP.timeV2});
}

const submitHandlerF = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFlowRateV({flowRate: detailsF.flowRateV, time: detailsF.timeV3});
}
```

The button tags

```
<button className="button-75 buttonsSign2"><span class="text" onClick={submitHandlerT}>Submit</span></button>

<button className="button-75 buttonsSign2" role="button"><span class="text" onClick={submitHandlerP}>Submit</span></button>

<button className="button-75 buttonsSign2" role="button"><span class="text" onClick={submitHandlerF}>Submit</span></button>
```

Not sure if it's relevant but to access this page I have to click a button which changes another state. It renders the component which contains the three buttons. However, I've done that with other parts of this project with no problems.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know whether it can help but you should remove the role="button" from both the second and third button. The “button” role is unnecessary for element “button”, especially if you use bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've done that but sadly to no avail

Comment: add onClick on the button and not on span?

Comment: you were right, I didn't realise I left the onclick in the spam, thanks! it works now